# What is the Big-O of this two-part algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

Given the following algorithm on a dataset of size N:

1. Separate the data into M=(N/lg N)
   blocks in O(N) time.
2. Partition the blocks in O(M lg M) time. *******

What is the big-O?  How do I evaluate (N/lg N) * lg (N/lg N) ?

If it is not O(N), is there an M small enough that the whole thing does become O(N)?

******* The partition algorithm is the STL's `stable_partition` which, in this example, will do M tests and at most M lg M swaps.  *But*, the items being swapped are blocks of size lg N.  Does this push the practical time of step 2 back up to O(N lg N) if they must be swapped in place?

*Not homework, just a working engineer poking around in comp-sci stuff.*

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "sort the blocks in O(M log M) time?"

Comment: @AShelly: No clue what stable_partition is supposed to do...

Comment: see http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stable_partition.html.  It in-place divides an array into 2 sub-arrays, based on a condition you supply, keeping the elements in each sublist in the original relative order.

Comment: @AShelly: How exactly do you call stable partition? According to your link, it only partitions into two...

Comment: @Moron: I do want to partition into 2 parts. (it's a version of this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2906789/10396).  I would call it with an iterator which worked on blocks of M items (`*i=*j++` copies M items to i and advances j by M).  The predicate would only need to inspect the first item in each block. (Actually, I'd probably do a custom version equivalent to that).

Comment: @AShelly: What is your ultimate goal? It seems like you want to sort, but you haven't talked about sorting the within the blocks themselves..

Comment: The goal is a binary partition in linear time as in the question I just linked. Step 1 ensures that all the items in each block have the same predicate, but leaves the two types intermixed.   Step 2 unmixes them - I'm trying to figure out if it really is linear too.

Comment: @AShelly: Don't you need a step 3 too? To merge the block so the the types are unmixed in the whole array? ALso what predicate are you considering? How would step 1 be O(N)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You evaluate by doing a bit of math.

`log(x/y) = log(x) - log(y)`
->
`log(N / log(N)) = log(N) - log(log(N))`

So, plugging this back in and combining into a single fraction.
`N(log(N) - log(log(N))) / log(N)`
=
`N - N(log(log(N)) / log(N))`
<=, since log(log(N)) <= log(N) as N -> inf., it's like multiplying by <= 1
`N`

So, the whole thing is O(N).

You can pretty easily guess that it is O(N log N) by noticing that `M = N / log N` is, itself, O(N). I don't know of a quick way to figure out that it's O(N) without a bit of doubt on my part due to having to multiply in the `log M`.

Answer (score 2):

It is O(N):

```
N / lgN * lg(N / lgN)=N / lgN * (lgN-lglgN)=N*(1-lglgN / lgN)<=N
```