# String to be synchronized in C

Tags: c, string, algorithm, sorting

Suppose i have a string "123a45b6c7de". Now i want to sort them like this "1234567abcde" but with the imposed condition that time complexity should be O(n). I tried with O(n^2) logic.Can Anyone suggest the logic with O(n).

Comment: @MitchWheat I think OP needs to sort the characters in a string not a set of strings. If that is the case counting sort is an easier and more appropriate solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stable separation for two classes of elements in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906789/stable-separation-for-two-classes-of-elements-in-an-array) (or close enough).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can sort the character in a string using [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) in linear time.

Comment: was just about to write the same